# I want to know how to connect my mongo client to my replication set

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, replication

I realized that the data oplog.rs is different from my client oplog.rs. Is the connection supposed to automatic once I initiated the replication set ? Or is there a step I missed in the process.

I was following this tutorial http://www.acemyskills.com/replica-sets-in-mongodb/

```
    config = {
        _id:"acemyskillsrepsets", 
        members: [
            {_id: 0, host: "localhost:27017"},
            {_id: 1, host: "localhost:27018"},
            {_id: 2, host: "localhost:27019"}
        ]
    };acemyskillsrepsets:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "acemyskillsrepsets",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-07-24T01:35:16.869Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(19),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "localhost:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 63,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1469324080, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(19)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-07-24T01:34:40Z"),
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1469324079, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-07-24T01:34:39Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 2,
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "localhost:27018",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 25,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1469324080, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(19)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-07-24T01:34:40Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-07-24T01:35:15.260Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-07-24T01:35:16.014Z"
),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "syncingTo" : "localhost:27019",
                        "configVersion" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "localhost:27019",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 42,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1469324080, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(19)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-07-24T01:34:40Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-07-24T01:35:16.020Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-07-24T01:35:15.622Z"
),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "syncingTo" : "localhost:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 2
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: can you show us the rs.status() from the primary node?

Comment: @zeugor I have added the rs.status()

Comment: the nodes with _id 1 and 2 have >>"state" : 8<<, it means DOWN (The member, as seen from another member of the set, is unreachable). Are you sure these instances are running?

Comment: @zeugor Okay, I turn them all on

Comment: then, is it working as you expected?

Comment: Maybe, I am confused on how replication and oplog works.  I thought that if I setup replication then whenever I do anything(add a collection, insert, delete) in my client my actions would be written into my replication set . For example, I open mongo --port 2710 and create a collection , then I would be able to view my actions in primary - oplog.rs .

Comment: your mongod instances are running on ports: 27017, 27018 and 27019. Why are you opening now to mongo on port 2710? Your initial question has a lack of information, so you can edit your question and be more precise and specify the commands you has used